# remember me in login form

Tags: asp.net

I had Login form ,and I added check box for remember me ,I did my code well but when I check rememeber me check box it rememeber only user name only.so please any one help me.

```
protected void CBRemeber_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie MyCookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
        bool IsRememberme = CBRemeber.Checked;
        if (IsRememberme)
        {
            MyCookie.Values.Add("UserName", TxtUser.Text);
            MyCookie.Values.Add("Password", TXTPassword.Text);
            MyCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);

        }
        else
        {
            MyCookie.Values.Add("UserName", string.Empty);
            MyCookie.Values.Add("Password", string.Empty);
            MyCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);

        }
        Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie);
    }
```

Comment: Do you encrypt you password any where?

Comment: I add property to txtpassword textmode=Password only

Comment: how do you assign the values to the textboxes? Perhaps it's there the problem.

Comment: best way to delete a cookie: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx, myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);

Answer (score -1):

You can't set the value of an ASP.NET Textbox control with `TextMode="Password"`. Instead you can use a plain HTML element,

```
<input id="tbPassword" type="password" value="Hello World!" />
```

which wil let you set the value. Server you can retrieve the value on postbacks using `Request.Form`.

Also note if you're using the built-in ASP.NET Login control, the ["Remember Me" checkbox behaves a little different](http://senfo.blogspot.com/2007/09/aspnet-login-control-remember-me-doesnt.html) than what you might expect.