# "Remember Me" in login form webmatrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, security

I've had an ASP.NET Razor site for a while now, and I'm sick of having to manually login every time. I'd like to use the rememberMe that comes built into all the WebMatrix samples and starter site templates. But I an't find docs for it.

And from what I can tell, even though in the samples, the rememberMe checkbox is there, it's not actually implemented.

How can we go about implementing this for a WebMatrix based site?

Comment: After _another_ search on S/O, I just came across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007956/remember-me-in-login-form?rq=1 I'm going to give that a go, and see how it works out and will update this question along the way.

Answer (score 4):

Search for [`FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx) and set the last parameter to **true**.